# Where do I set the URLs that appear under "support link" and "help link" in Programs and Features?

Tags: install4j

In install4j, where in the installer configuration do I set the URLs that show under "support link" and "help link" in Windows' "Programs and Features" screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are taken from the publisher URL field in the general settings step. As of install4j 5.1.11, there's no separate field for the help link.